# Pattern for creating a long running k8s custom resource using fabric8.io

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

How to controller for a Custom Resource relating to an external resource which takes a while to create?

I'm working on a creating a custom resource for standing up a CockroachLabs cloud database cluster, an operation which is kicked off via an API and takes 5+ minutes to complete.

Using the fabric8.io java library we have the CR created and working properly w.r.t. kicking-in when a CR is created or deleted.
But we have not yet figured out how to e.g. set a PENDING status on the CR and trigger a "re-try" where we can check the CockroachLabs API again to see if the DB cluster is ready or not to mark the CR status as successfully created.

We currently create a Watch from a MixedOperation for our CRD.

Any pointers to guides, docs or tutorials on how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you asking how to write a Kubernetes operator?  For setting Pending status you can have a field in your Custom Resource's status which you can read to trigger retry.

Comment: I had written a blogpost about this few years ago. It's a bit outdated but it might give you an idea about the control loop and reacting to changes using informers https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/10/07/write-a-simple-kubernetes-operator-in-java-using-the-fabric8-kubernetes-client#